# encrypt webapp in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, encryption

I'm about to install a web application on Tomcat at my client office.

The problem is that this application could be taken and installed at another office since all config files are in plain text.

I'm wondering if there is a way to deploy my web application on Tomcat using a password (or something, ...).

For example, this password should be saved outside Tomcat to not let anyone take the Tomcat installation with the application inside and use it elsewhere.

I'm not worrying about the Source code but the whole application should be encrypted somehow to not be be used by others.

Comment: OK. Lets assume for a moment that this is possible (it isn't). Once you have encrytped your web application Tomcat is going to need to decrypt it in order to run it. Where do you propose storing the decryption key and what stops the same person that is copying the web application copying the decryption key?

Comment: @MarkThomas , thank you for replying, this was just a thought but since it's not possible can you help me with another idea rather than encrypting my web application ?